# What's wrong with this INNER JOIN SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have three tables, tblMembers, tblBooks and tblReviews. The idea is a book review website.

Currently the Book Title is only displayed if there are reviews written for it, however I want the book title to always be displayed along with; either a list of reviews, or, the text, 'this title has not yet been reviewed.'

What is wrong with this SQL query?

```
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM tblBooks
INNER JOIN tblReviews
ON tblBooks.bookID = tblReviews.bookID
INNER JOIN tblMembers
ON tblReviews.userID = tblMembers.userID
WHERE tblReviews.bookID = :bookID";


$query = $odb->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute(array(":bookID" => $bookID));

    $results = $query->fetchAll();
    echo "<h1>".$results[0]['longTitle']."</h1>";
    if($results !== FALSE && $query->rowCount()>0) {
        foreach($results as $result) {
            echo "Reviewed by: " . $result['firstName'] . " " . $result['lastName'];
            echo "<br />";
            echo "Rating: " . $result['rating']."/100";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "Date: " . $result['reviewDate'] . " " . $result['reviewTime'];
            echo "<br />";
            echo "Review:";
            echo "<br />";
            echo $result['reviewText'];
            echo "<hr />";
        }
    } else { // the book has not been reviewed yet
        echo "There are no reviews for this title yet";
    }
```

As mentioned above, the line `echo "<h1>".$results[0]['longTitle']."</h1>";` is only executed if the book has reviews, I want to get the book details prior to checking if it has reviews or not. How can I do this?

On another note, how can I check which books haven't been reviewed yet and populate a drop down list with the results? - This has been answered :D

How can I either:

Populate two separate drop down lists, one for books that have reviews and one for books that haven't been reviewed yet (this one I can do as I have the SQL from the question above).

OR

Populate the single dropdown list but put books that have reviews at the top, separated by a string of characters, let's say "---------- THESE BOOKS HAVEN'T BEEN REVIEWED YET ----------" followed by the books that haven't yet been reviewed. Is this possible?

Comment: you can't. you're doing inner joins, which means you get results if matching records exist in ALL the joined tables. if there's no reviews, you get no records, and hence no title. you'd have to do at least TWO queries, or switch to using LEFT joins.

Comment: How do I use LEFT JOINS, please can you provide an example.

Comment: User LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN - INNER JOIN wouldn't work

Comment: Every thing is ok just change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_join#Left_outer_join

Comment: Consider this:  SQL is little more than "set logic" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html  This example shows most of the join types and what you should  expect back in the form of data.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert, is there any chance you could help me out on another matter, I want to list all books which have not been reviewed. It is probably really simple but I can't think of the way to do it.

Comment: @Mike Change the where in the below to be `WHERE tblReviews.bookID is null`.  The absence of a record in tblReviews means it's not been reviewed.  Again refer to that coding horror link it really helps explain the joins and how to get what you're after.

Comment: @xQbert how can I populate a list with books that have reviews listed first then the ones that don't at the bottom?

Comment: @Mike add an order by clause after the where.  ORDER By tblReviews.BookID Asc  or Order by tblReviews.BookID DESC.  Alternatively you can use `coalesce(tblReviews.BookID,999999999999)` to replace BookID with some absurd value which will never be reached and just sort ascending.

Comment: I wanted to split them/remove them from that particular list. I've edited the question to reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblBooks
LEFT JOIN tblReviews
ON tblBooks.bookID = tblReviews.bookID
LEFT JOIN tblMembers
ON tblReviews.userID = tblMembers.userID
WHERE tblReviews.bookID = :bookID
```

Will return all books regardless if there is a review or a member affiliated with it.

IF there is a review return it, and if the review has a member it as well.  otherwise NULL values will come back in  fields related to tblMembers or tblReviews.